# Ng Serve Throws Multipe Syntax Errors for Ngrx

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am trying to go through an angular course to learn ngrx. I have to teach it in a couple months, so I am trying to refresh my brain on the concept. For some reason, after I installed it and made sure there were no errors in the code I wrote, the errors are coming from a generated file in node_modules. However, when I go into the file, there are no red underlines or errors that my IDE sees. It only shows the errors when I run ng serve.

Generated File (feature_creator_models.d.ts):

```
export declare type FeatureSelector<AppState extends Record<string, any>, FeatureName extends keyof AppState & string, FeatureState extends AppState[FeatureName]> = {
    [K in FeatureName as `select${Capitalize<K>}State`]: MemoizedSelector<AppState, FeatureState>;
};
export declare type NestedSelectors<AppState extends Record<string, any>, FeatureState> = FeatureState extends Primitive | unknown[] | Date ? {} : {
    [K in keyof FeatureState & string as `select${Capitalize<K>}`]: MemoizedSelector<AppState, FeatureState[K]>;
};
declare type Primitive = string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined;
export {};
```

Error Codes:

```
3     [K in FeatureName as `select${Capitalize<K>}State`]: MemoizedSelector<AppState, FeatureState>;
                        ~~
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/feature_creator_models.d.ts:3:48 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

3     [K in FeatureName as `select${Capitalize<K>}State`]: MemoizedSelector<AppState, FeatureState>;
                                                 ~
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/feature_creator_models.d.ts:6:43 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

6     [K in keyof FeatureState & string as `select${Capitalize<K>}`]: MemoizedSelector<AppState, FeatureState[K]>;
                                            ~~~~~~~
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/feature_creator_models.d.ts:6:50 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

6     [K in keyof FeatureState & string as `select${Capitalize<K>}`]: MemoizedSelector<AppState, FeatureState[K]>;
                                                   ~
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/feature_creator_models.d.ts:6:64 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

6     [K in keyof FeatureState & string as `select${Capitalize<K>}`]: MemoizedSelector<AppState, FeatureState[K]>;
                                                                 ~
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/feature_creator_models.d.ts:10:1 - error TS1160: Unterminated template literal.

10 
   
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/reducer_creator.d.ts:31:16 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

31     ...creators: Creators,
  [0m                ~
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/reducer_creator.d.ts:32:12 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

32     reducer: OnReducer<State extends infer S ? S : never, Creators>
```

Comment: I think there is a mismatch between your version of `TypeScript` and the version of `TypeScript` that your version of `ngrx` requires.

Comment: Is there a way to check what version ngrx requires of TypeScript?

Comment: If you're using the latest version (version 12 I believe), it is 4.2.4. I look at the package.json in the repository. https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/package.json

Answer (score 1):

Go to **package.json**, and change the version of **@ngrx/store**,

> 1. **@ngrx/store": "^8.0.0-beta.2"**
> 2. ***run npm install***, for installing the dependencies
> 3. ***run ng serve***